# Can't download from App Store

Tags: mac-appstore

A click on "Install App" does nothing. No error message, no download. 
I am trying to download an app appropriate for my installed OS.

I've rebooted and signed out/in at the app store. No change.

I'm editing because this appears to be the same issue. I signed out and into the app store, and am trying to update existing software.

[image]

This is the resulting error message. It references "other account" but this is the account I use, exact same ID I just signed in with.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what app were you attempting to download?  I ran into this yesterday when trying to download Yosemite from a Mac running 10.6.8.

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/numi/id484388250?mt=12&ign-mpt=uo%3D4 - numi a free (today) calculator app. But then I tried other downloads, none would work. Nor would an update to an app I already own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling with the error message of "updates for other accounts", I found a solution to all of it.

The apple forums offered the solution through the [debug option](https://discussions.apple.com/message/22568456#22568456).

Type `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true` into terminal and a combination of Cache Buster, Clear Cookies and Reset App did the trick.

[image]

After that, the apps were able to update. FWIW, I tried download a new app, but wasn't quickly able to find a Snow Leo app. 10 tries, and all wanted a newer OS.

Answer (score 2):

Try resetting the Mac App Store.

1. Enable the debug menu and restart the Mac App Store.

   ```
   defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true
   ```
2. Choose the **Reset Application** option and restart the Mac App Store.

   [image: App Store Debug Menu]

Comment: Thanks. I went through the steps above, and no change. Now trying to figure out if I can reload just the Store or I need to reinstall full OS to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe deleting Mac App Store cache can help you.
Open Terminal and type:

`open $TMPDIR../C/`

This should open Finder. Delete the com.apple.appstore folder and relaunch Mac App Store see if it works.

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, you just need to sign out and sign in again to the Appstore. Worked for me.