# Removing all of an Application?

Tags: applications, mac-appstore

I am having an issue with the [AppStore](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/161596/cant-download-from-app-store), and this is a related, but different question.

How do I find and remove all bits of the AppStore application? Besides the obvious app itself, sitting in the application folder, what prefs, helpers, etc are there that must be removed?

I ask this because when I removed the application file, deleted it, and reinstalled (from 10.6.6 updater image), the app icon showed a pending update the moment it launched, and it showed that I was signed in to my account. This implies there's more stuff I need to delete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very tricky. From 10.6.6 (when Apple released the Mac App Store), the App Store has been pretty deeply built in to the system. You can see this by the fact that if you click on the  in your Menu Bar, there is an option to launch the App Store from there.

In later versions of OS X it is even more deeply embedded as software updates for the OS are downloaded through the App Store. In order to completely remove all trace of the App Store and still have a stable system that won't crash or kernel panic, you would have to dig in to some of the Apple Frameworks and binaries to remove references for the App Store.

Comment: Thanks, it's sounding like there's no delete/reinstall, only a full OS wipe/install.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't give you better news! If this post has answered your question satisfactorily, please could you mark the question as answered so as to move it from the "Unanswered" section. Thanks

Comment: Done. Strange stuff. I understand the issue is that it's embedded into OS, sort of.